# Why do I need to cast when using bounded type parameter

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I was playing around with generics and now I am curious why I need to cast the "new Special()" to E before adding it to the Set. 
I know that this is not really needed in this case, because I could use a Set of Base as well...

```
private static class Base {}
private static class Special extends Base{}

private <E extends Base> Set<E> doSomething(){
    Set<E> someset = new HashSet<>();
    someset.add(new Special());
    return someset;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you had this:

```
final class SomethingElse extends Base {}
```

and this:

```
private <E extends Base> doSomething(Set<E> someset) {
   someset.add(new Special());
}
```

Can you see the problem now?

`E extends Base` means that "`E` is an *unknown* type that extends `Base`". It doesn't mean "`E` is *any* type that extends `Base`."

In the example above, the problem is that one could call `doSomething()` like this:

```
Set<Special> onlySpecials = new HashSet<>();
doSomething(onlySpecials);
onlySpecials.stream()
  .findFirst()
  .ifPresent(Special::someSpecializedMethod); /* Boom! ClassCastException! */
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that `Base` have two subtype: `Special` and `VerySpecial`.
And you call `doSomething` like this:

```
Set<VerySpecial> set = doSomething();
```

In this case your `set` will contain `Special` instance which is not what you expected because its type don not allow that.